# jQuery Cycle with anchors and thumbnails

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I'm using the jQuery Cycle plugin to build a slideshow that the main image is wrapped in an anchor and also has the thumbnail navigation.  I basically have the same code from the [demo page](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager2.html) of jQuery Cycle.  Once I wrapped the images in a link the thumbnails broke.  I have tried dropping the "slide.src" for `$('#slideshow img).attr('src')` but that still comes back as undefined.

```
$('#slideshow').before('<ul id="slideshow-nav">').cycle({
 fx: 'fade',
 speed: 'slow',
 timeout: 0,
 pager: '#slideshow-nav',

 pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide){
 return '<li class="thumbnail"><a href="#"><img class="rounded" src="' + slide.src + '" width="137" height="129" /></a><span class="highlight"></span><span class="gloss"></span></li>';
 }
});
```

And my html is this.

```
<div id="slideshow">
 <a href="#"><img src="images/gyro.jpg"  alt="Gyro"></a>
 <a href="#"><img src="images/gyro.jpg"  alt="Gyro"></a>
 <a href="#"><img src="images/gyro.jpg"  alt="Gyro"></a>
 <a href="#"><img src="images/gyro.jpg"  alt="Gyro"></a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply a valid HTML fragment to `$.before()`. At the moment you have no closing `</ul>` tag. The cleanest way to do this is to self-close the tag:

```
$('#slideshow').before('<ul id="slideshow-nav" />').cycle({ ...
```

If you're using Firebug or the developer tools in a Webkit browser you can always see what elements jQuery is finding by writing `console.log($("#slideshow-nav"));` or `console.log($(slide));` in your callback function.

Comment: Yea I have logged them and they just come back as undefined.  This occurred after I wrapped the images in #slideshow in an anchor.  Prior to that it worked.

Comment: It may be that adding the `<a>` is breaking the selector that the plugin uses. If you're just trying to get a hand cursor when you rollover the thumbnail then use `cursor: pointer;` in CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I found an error elsewhere in my script that is modifying the thumbnails that was for some reason breaking the images.